# Is the tag [simultaneous-bilingualism] useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have seen that some questions have the tag: [simultaneous-bilingualism](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simultaneous-bilingualism). I'm am wondering whether that makes sense at all. As far as I understand it, it is to indicate someone with two native languages.

But I think that tag will be hard to find for askers, simultaneous is misleading, and I am not sure there is a need for a specific tag for that.

Comment: [Simultaneous Bilingualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_bilingualism) is a specific phenomenon, and probably deserves its own tag, for questions about this phenomenon. Why do you think it's confusing?

Comment: Fair enough, learned something new. The confustion comes from the fact that simultaneous refers to the acquisition and not the bilingualism, which is, in itself, simultaneous.

Comment: Perhaps it's a confusing term... but at this point it is a fixed term, and I think we're pretty powerless (in the grand scheme of things) to change it.

Comment: Since the tag is useful, should we also add [tag:sequential-bilingualism]?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe you should probably ask a separate question, not sure people will see that comment on a post that is a few months old.

Answer (score 2):

Simultaneous Bilingualism is a very specific term who's meaning is mistaken for a lot of the site's function: Being proficient in more than one language.

The more accurate terminology to fit your description is [simultaneous-acquisition]: acquiring 2+ languages at the same time.

We need to clarify (via a helpful comment) and edit out those tags in favour of another if the tag is mistaken.

Comment: As much as I don't like the term, it is actually a specific expression indicating when a child learns two languages in parallel, from birth. So it isn't a meta tag for all we do, as most of our questions are about acquiring a L2, L3, etc. at older age (compared to birth).

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin thanks for clarifying: see my update